# How to prevent form.target from causing all HTTP GET in history from doing another roundtrip to the server?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Alright, I'm using form.target to open content in a new window.  However, when I do this and then hit the back button on my browser, I find any entry resulting from a GET is doing another round trip to the server.  This is a problem because session variables may have been changed in the interim, so the new GET no longer matches the old one.

I'm using C# and javascript for this web application, if it helps any.

This behavior occurs on IE8, but not on Firefox 10.  Is there any way to prevent it in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a semi-random ID as a querystring on the URL.

I also added this to my OnInit event.  For some reason explicitly setting the cache settings helps.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=600");
```

Combined, this gave the page uniqueness and enforced the browser caching.  This prevented the browser from always retrieving the most recent version of the page when encountering a GET operation in the browsing history.